# Using read command

Tags: bash, unix

I am extremely confused about using the read command. Can someone please explain this to me? For example if I have:

An executable file called `script`, containing

```
read first second
echo $first
echo $second
```

and you call it with:

```
echo This is a line of input | ./script
```

What happens and why? I can't get it to work and something is supposed to displayed

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html

Comment: Also learn to put double quotes around variable interpolations now rather than later. It doesn't matter here but it will, soon. `echo "$first"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `help read` gives this info:

> The line is split into fields as with word splitting, and the first
>   word is assigned to the first NAME, the second word to the second
>   NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to the last NAME.

So what's happening here is that the first word is assigned to the variable `$first`, and the rest of the input line assigned to the last variable `$second`.

If you want to keep the first word in `$first` and the second word in `$second`, try adding a `$third` variable.

Comment: Ah, thank you. So this means nothing is displayed on monitor after, correct?

Comment: `So this means nothing is displayed on monitor after, correct?`????

Comment: @Rahat: in your example, it should print "This" on one line, followed by "is a line of input" on the second line. If it doesn't do this, something is wrong, but we'll need more info to troubleshoot it.